# Ajax Data Lost and cannot be retrieved

Tags: jquery, ajax

I send Ajax request using GET. One of the parameters (to) is lost and cannot be retrieved on the called file using $_GET["to"].

Now what is the problem ? Some of file working well with this function !

```
function SendEmail(To, Subject, Message) 
{
var URL = 'mail-service.php?&msg=' + escape(Message) + 'to=' + escape(To) + '&subject=' + escape(Subject);
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (res) {
        alert("Message Sent to : " + res);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check yout ajax  url get parameter I think you forget adding `&`

```
var URL = 'mail-service.php?&msg=' + escape(Message) + '&to=' + escape(To) + '&subject=' + escape(Subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use URL parameters, use the `data:` field to `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        msg: Message,
        to: To,
        subject: Subject
    },
    success: function (res) {
        alert("Message Sent to : " + res);
    }
});
```

This will automatically ensure that all of the parameters are correctly escaped and encoded for posting to the PHP script.

FWIW, using `GET` seems a bit odd for this - I would expect to use `POST`.